# alter domain type

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have a domain type of varchar(35) and would like to increase the length to 40.

I can create a new domain and just do ALTER TABLE table ALTER COLUMN column TYPE new_domain;

However, I would have to do this for all tables that use the domain. Is there anyway to use the ALTER DOMAIN syntax to increase the length/change data type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The superior design would be to have columns of [data type `text`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-character.html) allowing unlimited length of text. If you actually need to enforce a maximum length, add a `CHECK` constraint like this:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl ADD CONSTRAINT tbl_col_len CHECK (length(col) < 41);
```

You can freely change a check constraint without having to mess with the column or its data type.

The same is true for domains. If you enforce a length restriction on a domain with a check constraint, you can freely change it (of course all columns using the domain must match the new criteria. For all I know you can not as easily change the underlying data type.

---

With an existing setup like yours, you could also dump the database, hack the dump with a global search & replace to exchange all occurrences the domain (as long as all fields using the domain fulfill the criteria) and reload the dump.